# auth0 stops works after updating angular angular2-jwt and a bunch of node modules

Tags: javascript, angular, auth0

So when i began updating my node modules and other things to the newest version. My auth0 login stopped work correctly even though before the update. It was working fine. But now my login doesn't even work correct any longer and i don't know what happened. When I looked into the localstorage and I saw that the email_verified returning false despite the login is correct. I suspect that it a problem with the angular2-jwt being updated but not completely sure.
 https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-authentication based the login off this article but don't know what changes happened.

```
 // services/auth.service.ts
    import { Injectable,  NgZone } from '@angular/core';
    import {Router} from '@angular/router';
    import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';


    // We want to avoid any 'name not found'
    // warnings from TypeScript
    declare var Auth0Lock: any;

    @Injectable()
    export class AuthenticationService {
        constructor( private _router: Router, private _zone: NgZone) {}

        lock = new Auth0Lock('clientid', 'domain');

        login() {
            this.lock.show((error: string, profile: Object, id_token: string) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                // We get a profile object for the user from Auth0
                localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
                // We also get the user's JWT
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);
            });
        }

        logout() {
            // To log out, we just need to remove
            // the user's profile and token
            localStorage.removeItem('profile');
            localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
        }

        loggedIn() {
            return tokenNotExpired();
        }
    }
```

navbar.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
      &#9776;
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
      <a class="navbar-brand display-nav" [routerLink]="['/home']"></a>

      <div class="nav navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" [routerLink]="['/home']">
          Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link"  [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="auth.login()" >Login</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="auth.logout()"  >Logout</a>
      </div>

      <div class="nav navbar-nav  float-xs-right">
        <db-cart-menu   ></db-cart-menu>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

navbar_component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'db-navbar',
  templateUrl: 'app/navbar/navbar.component.html',
  providers: [ AuthenticationService ]
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {}
  login() {
    this.auth.login();
  }
  logout() {
    this.auth.logout();
  }
  loggedIn () {
    this.auth.loggedIn();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to include the errors that are being output in the console? Did you look there for clues?

Comment: the only error that I found that isn't vague was looking in the local storage and  the profile having the email verified return false.